# git commit asking for who you are

Tags: git, git-commit

I ran into below error message while trying to make some commits.

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

    Run

      git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
      git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

The issue could be solved by typing instructed command as shown. I just wonder why did such message occur? I have used git for a while now, normally it would just commit and add files without any message like this.

Comment: Then you have deleted your global .git config.

Comment: Check if your email and name are configured `git config --list` or `git config --list --global`

Comment: @Stony Hi, can you give me more details? thanks

Comment: @RohanKumar After adding them, I can now see the newly added names, what does this list do?

Comment: @Max_Guo: It provides a list of all variables set in config file. See `man git-config` for more information.

Comment: I've been having this issue in Ubuntu 18.04 with git installed from the repositories. Git seems to forget the name and email, but all other settings are still set in `.gitconfig`. I set it with global, it appears in `.gitconfig`, and then somehow it disappears again (after a reboot I suspect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default git is looking into different places to find a global config file.

`~/.gitconfig` or `~/.config/git/config` and after that it's looking into `.git/config` into your project folder. Normally you save your global settings in one of the first two config file. If you switch your user or delete that file your global settings are lost. You can read  more about in the git configuration.

https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: Good stuff man! I'm trying to make a new commit to push some of my codes to a different remote repo in github, I believe this could be the cause! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So that your name and email can be shown in git history. If you work alone, then it might not seem vital to you, but when you work in a team it's crucial. Otherwise it would pick up your username from your system username, which might not always be desired.

Comment: In this case, do I need to retype my name and mail in the future? or the system will just pick up from the history from now on. Also I didn't remember to do such things before, but my old commits appear to work just fine. Any idea?

Comment: You just need to add your username and email to `~/.gitconfig` file. This command automatically does that for you. It needs to be done only once. Sometimes people change their laptop or their username, which leads to their newer commits on different names leading to discrepancies. So it's just a preemptive measure.

Comment: I see! Thanks for your help, will accept your answer if now better answer given in 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically done to set your **accounts default identity**.That is when you are commit requests on git it won't matter to you that much if you are working on that particular project alone but if you are working on some project as a team it is important to set the accounts identity so that there are no issues later.
However if you are user who usually or wants to **work alone** you can add your username and email to **~/.gitconifig file** .Once this is done you won't have to **git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"**
every time update it. Also you can simply **Omit --global** to *set the identity only in this repository.*